# How to read an integer which appears right after new line in c?

Tags: c, scanf

```
int fscanf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...);
```

I can use `fscanf()` to read an integer from file. How can I read an integer that's *right after a newline*?

Comment: We'll need more details if you want a different answer than the one I gave below.

Comment: A newline is *whitespace*. It is ignored by the `scanf()` conversion specifier `"%d"` (among others). You don't need any special treatment to deal with an integer that's right after a newline; just do a normal call: `fscanf(stream, "%d", &variable);`

Answer (score 2):

[`fscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/) - look at the example.

Here's what you seem to want:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    FILE * pFile;

    pFile = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");

    // Repeat this as many times as necessary
    fscanf(pFile, "\n%d", &n);
    printf("%d\n", n);

    fclose(pFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Except he said right after a newline, not right before a new line.

Comment: @jet, does `fscanf` set the file offset internally ,so that the next call will return the next match element?

Comment: @lexer Yup. You can use `fseek()` to move the 'internal offset' to a different location, though.

Answer (score 0):

`scan` till a newline and then read an `int`. e.g do:

```
fscanf(filePointer, "%s\n%d", firstline, &theInteger);
```

The format might need to be modified if there are more things on the line.

Comment: You might need to ensure that `firstLine` is larger than the largest line. ;)